# Query AzureADExtensionProperty from Graph api

Tags: azure, azure-ad-graph-api

When i run this command i get the extension property list.
Get-AzureADExtensionProperty

```
7da33d44-be79-4325-bad6-768125698316 extension_33e0eb1e326c430ea21852abdc035ac7_Fin_Role    {User}
0b3ff694-6b8a-4b1a-9d54-062b475289f6 extension_33e0eb1e326c430ea21852abdc035ac7_Contributor {User}
1d421ded-a7ed-4d6d-8e82-5erf012543bc extension_33e0eb1e326c430ea21852abdc035ac7_Reader      {User}
```

how can i get the same records using graph api.

i already tried using https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/id/extensionProperties but i got an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please verify the application id you are using is correct?

You can get List of application id by running the URL-https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/

Then enter the application Id to URL - [https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/{id}/extensionProperties](https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/applications/%7Bid%7D/extensionProperties) and retry the operation.